# App Inventor and Web App connectivity

Tags: android, web-services, asp.net-mvc-4, app-inventor

I have created a mobile app using app inventor 2 and and web application using mvc.net4. I want the two to connect to the same database. Which is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

you can access a MySQL database with the web component of App Inventor together with a php script on your server, see the [App Inventor - MySQL interface](http://puravidaapps.com/mysql.php)